# How to lookup against a range and return count of a dimension in R

Tags: r, excel, dplyr

I have the NYC Flights data in which one of the dimensions (see last column) is the destination

[NYC Flights Data Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjb6o.png)

I've got another dataframe where I've got the distinct destinations

[Distinct Destinations Data Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEt3A.png)

Now I want to add a 2nd column in this dataset which should be the count of flights for that destination as per earlier dataset. Think of `countif`and `lookup` equivalent of MS-Excel in R

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first dataframe is called `df1` and the second one is `df2`, you can use :

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% count(dest) %>% right_join(df2, by = 'dest')
```

This will return `NA`'s for `dest` present in `df2` which are not in `df1`. If you want to replace them with 0, you can do :

```
df1 %>% 
  count(dest) %>% 
  right_join(df2, by = 'dest') %>%
  mutate(n = replace(n, is.na(n), 0))
```